# libgdx forcing manifest file to change on export

Tags: android, android-manifest, libgdx, screen-orientation

In the beginning of making a game for android using LibGDX.

Having an issue:

I want this game to run in portrait mode.

I set the relevant line in the manifest file to

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

However, every time I export the game into an .apk for testing, that line automatically changes back to "landscape" (the default setting) during the export process.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

are you cleaning the android project before running?

set  orientation

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

then clean your android project and then run it.